# Best Javascript Grid for SharePoint REST returning data

Tags: jquery

I've managed to write  jQuery code that returns  the data for a SharePoint doc library. is there a best method or a clean framework to render that returning json data as a grid that look pretty close to sharepoint or office look and feel?

Comment: If you want SharePoint look and feel then Office UI Fabric is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at datatables?
https://editor.datatables.net/examples/advanced/deepObjects.html

Answer (score 3):

The MVPs are busy with https://github.com/ngOfficeUIFabric/ng-officeuifabric/

which has a Table component: http://ngofficeuifabric.com/demos/uifTable/

You need to go for AngularJS and do more programming yourself,

jQuery dataTables is more plug and pray